How to use multiple API modules in a single testing file?
Disclaimer: first Stack Overflow post, and very new to pytest.
I'm a part of a very new QA team in the company. Right now we are focusing on creating initial tests for various Sync APIs (most of them are posting/getting data from a SQL database).
We are using python/pytest.
Every API has an auto-generated Python package that we use in testing of that API.
Every package has a "Configuration" module, "ApiClient" module and various API modules for different parts of the API.
Our file structure for testing:
API-tests
│
├─ \__init_\_.py
├─ **conftest.py**
│(different APIs)
├─ CloudControlDbAPI
├─ WeatherForecastDbAPI
├─ WeatherForecastAPI
└─ AssetConfigurationProvider
       ├─ **conftest.py**    
       └─ tests    
               ├─ test_battery_api.py    
               ├─ test_battery_inverter_api.py    
               ├─ test_device_api.py    
               └─ data (data folder with some known objects used for testing.

In the "root" conftest file:
import inspect
import re
import pytest


# get args
__options = ['host', 'username', 'password']


def pytest_addoption(parser):
    for opt in __options:
        parser.addoption(f'--{opt}')


# init module
@pytest.fixture
def api(config, api_client, module, request):
    args = {k: request.config.getoption(k) for k in __options if request.config.getoption(k)}
    config = config(**args)
    api = api_client(configuration=config, header_name='Test', header_value=0)
    api = module(api_client=api)
    return api

The api() fixture is what we eventually use in the tests. It uses "config", "api_client" and "module".
Every API has a different "Configuration" and "ApiClient" modules, and various api "modules".
Each API folder (CloudControlDbAPI/WeatherForecastAPI/AssetConfigurationProvider) has it's own conftest.py file:
from {API}_python_client import Configuration, ApiClient
import inspect
import re
import pytest


# Init #
@pytest.fixture(scope='session')
def config():
    return Configuration


@pytest.fixture(scope='session')
def api_client():
    return ApiClient


@pytest.fixture(scope='session')
def file_path():
    return __file__

So the naming of the Configuration and ApiClient is the same, but for every API it comes from a different package.
For example in the WeatherForecastDbAPI:
from WeatherForecastApis.WeatherForecastDb_python_client import Configuration, ApiClient

In the AssetConfigurationProvider:
from AssetConfigurationDataProvider_python_client import Configuration, ApiClient

Some of the APIs have one api-module, and some have multiple.
each test file had its own module fixture:
from AssetConfigurationDataProvider_python_client import **BatteryApi**
from data.batteries import *
import pytest


@pytest.fixture(scope='module')
def module():
    return **BatteryApi**

# Tests #

@pytest.mark.parametrize("known_battery", known_batteries_list)
def test_get_battery_by_id(**api: BatteryApi**, known_battery: Battery):
    res = api.get_battery_by_id(known_battery.site_entity_id)
    assert res.model.model_id == known_battery.model_id
    assert res.parameters == known_battery.parameters

Every test uses the api() fixture from the "root" conftest, which uses the config/api_client/module fixtures from the child conftest of each API.
The Question is!
How can we modify our conftest/fixtures, to be able to use multiple API modules in the same file or even in the same test?
Right now, the api() fixture inherits the "module" fixture from the file the test is running from, but what if we want to use the "BatteryApi" and "BatteryManagingApi" modules, in the same file/test?
What can we change in the structure of the api fixture or the module fixture, to be able to use both BatteryManagingApi and BatteryApi in the same test?
from AssetConfigurationDataProvider_python_client import BatteryManagingApi, BatteryApi

@pytest.fixture(scope='module')
def module():
    return BatteryManagingApi

I've tried to create a class to contain all the fixtures we use, but not sure if this is the best practice, or if there is a way simpler way I'm just not seeing.
What I've tried:
class Bse_Test_Api:
    def __init__(self, config, api_client): 
        self._config = config
        self._api_client = api_client
        # self._module_list = module_list

    def api(self, module, **args):
        config = self._config(**args)
        api = self._api_client(configuration=config, header_name='Test', header_value=0)
        api = module(api_client=api)
        return api

